# Why do people add <!--// ...//--> round their javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I remember reading something about it a few years back but I don't remember anymore.

Was it something to do with IE and parsing it as plain text...?

Comment: Who exactly is it that adds `//*` around their JavaScript code?  I don't think I've ever seen it.

Comment: Never seen it. You probably mean the HTML comment around JS code?

Comment: You're thinking of the `<!--//` and `//-->` I think..

Comment: https://github.com/pipwerks/CaptivateController/blob/master/CaptivateController.js Has it around the debug code... or was this a commented out group comment.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about `<!--//` I just saw `//*` and got confused between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean CDATA

[source](http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm)

> This fixes the validator. The problem is that some older web browsers
>   don't understand the CDATA tag and so this breaks your Javascript in
>   those web browsers. Fortunately, Javascript multi-line comments start
>   and finish with characters that do not cause validation errors. We can
>   therefore comment out the CDATA tag in so far as the Javascript
>   processors within the web browsers are concerned while still leaving
>   the Javascript content defined as CDATA as far as the validator is
>   concerned. We do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
// content of your Javascript goes here
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't the real reason so that JS  wouldn't display as text in browsers that didn't know about the `script` tag? No longer a concern today

Comment: I've heard of problems when using `<` in the js

Comment: @EricFortis A bare `<` is fine in any browser used by any meaningful fraction of the population.

Answer (score 3):

HTML comment tags `<!--` and `-->` should be added around JavaScript to prevent old browsers that don't understand JS from displaying it as text. It is best to put the JavaScript "comment to end of line" characters `//` in front of the closing HTML comment tag so JavaScript doesn't interpret that as code. Technically, browsers with *no* understanding of JS are *extremely* rare, but it doesn't hurt anything and costs maybe a total of 15 bytes.

In the end, I usually do something like this, mostly out of habit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var scriptHere="whatever";
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Don't say that *it should*, say that if you need to support browsers from before 1995

Comment: Right; it's completely unnecessary in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a wild guess here... do you mean things like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
function doStuff() {
    alert('Yadayadayada');
}
//]]></script>
```

(Variations include `<!--` as the first line and `//-->` as the last line, as `<!--` is also a *line* comment in JavaScript.)

It may have had something to do with older browsers interpreting it as text, but in that respect, you definitely don't have to worry about it any more.

The other part is validity. Certain characters used in JavaScript, say, `<` and `>` for comparison and `&` for AND operations, aren't valid XML. Putting them in a CDATA block makes them valid. I don't know of any browser that will cause problems because of this, however.

The best way to deal with this, of course, is to just link to external scripts using `src`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/whatever.js"> </script>
```

It separates content from behaviour nicely, unclutters your markup, leverages caching and parallel downloads, and lets you not worry about things like this.

Comment: please don't give that as generic advice. it should only be a external script, if the contents are not small (~10kb) or are not in the visible viewport upon page load. if it is in the viewport (and small enough) it is better to keep in as a block script. if it is not in the viewport, it is better to use it as a defered loaded script. https://varvy.com/pagespeed/critical-render-path.html

Comment: @scones: Page speed isn’t the only consideration. If you need to aggressively optimize uncached loads, you should know enough to know when the generic advice does and doesn’t apply. Otherwise, external scripts are important for allowing the average developer to create restrictive CSPs. HTTP/2 push also lets you keep the consistency and simplicity of external scripts while creating a good load time balance.

Comment: correct. http2 has a nice "synergy" to this, but also was not mentioned. generic advice is fine, but should always be supplemented by the additional information under certain circumstances (like performance) - or at least a mention of exceptions from the rule. (ie. further techniques may include http2 and/or critical-path-rendering )

Comment: and your nickname is not directly referenceable for some reason. :)