# Sublime Text 2 Snippet: How can I escape a double closing square bracket?

Tags: escaping, sublimetext2

To speed things up for me, I'd like to create a Sublime Text 2 snippet that outputs the following code (taken from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10988805/937084)):

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
/* ]]> */
```

I tried this:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/* <![CDATA[ */
/* ]]> */
]]></content>
    <description>JavaScript: CDATA</description>
    <tabTrigger>jsc</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

But when I use the above code, this is the output I get:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
/*
```

Notice that the `]]> */` portion is missing. I've tried escaping it, but can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No ideas, but i can suggest a trick:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/* <![CDATA[ */
/*  ${1:]]}> */
]]></content>
    <description>JavaScript: CDATA</description>
    <tabTrigger>jsc</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

An extra TAB is required but it works.